# Grouping controllers and views in Rails MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to do something similar to the question here:
[Grouping Views, Controllers, Models in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848034/grouping-views-controllers-models-in-mvc)

But in Ruby on Rails. And the catch is, Models are to be grouped in a folder, but Controllers and Views are to be put in different folders, say admin/ and store/ folders.

Tried to separate these in a project, but problem is:

```
  map.connect 'projects/:id', :controller => 'gallery/projects', :action => 'show'
  map.namespace(:gallery,  :active_scaffold => true) do |gallery|
    gallery.resources :projects, :comments
  end
```

With that, gallery_project_path(@project) returns /gallery/projects/xxx (I want it to be /projects/xxx)

Is this possible with Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want `/projects` routes then `map.namespace` isn't the option you want.  Try just specifiy the name of the controller

```
map.resources :projects, :controller => 'gallery/projects'
```

That should generate routes like these

```
GET /projects/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"gallery/projects", :action=>"show"}
PUT /projects/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"gallery/projects", :action=>"update"}
```

You should also check out the RailsGuide: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  I always start there when I have routing issues.